# Image positioning next to header in css

Tags: html, css

Im having a bit of trouble trying to position an image in my website.
Im trying to get this main photo to be right next to the "Work" header and have it scale in place when changing the window size. (just how the paragraph above does)

Additionally, how would I go about adding 2 images under that main image but both side by side?

any help would be great.

```css
.AboutMeContainer {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.mainheaders {
  color: rgb(101, 118, 143);
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  padding-left: 95px;
}

.mainheaderscontainer {
  display: flex;
  padding-inline: 6px 20px;
  border-right: 3px solid rgb(101, 118, 143);
}

.aboutMeParagraphContainer {
  padding-inline: 20px;
  padding-right: 80px
}

.Workcontainer {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 16px;
}

#mainworkcontainer {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.workImages {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.imagecard {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2rem;
  float: right;
  width: 45%;
  opacity: 0.8;
  margin-top: -240px;
  border: solid rgb(101, 118, 143);
}

.imagecard:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.imagecard:first-child {
  width: 65%;
}

#bigimage {
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Lerantino</h1>
  <nav class="topnav">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="AboutMe" href="">About Me</a></li>
      <li><a class="Work" href=""> Work</a></li>
      <li><a class="Contact Me" href="">Contact Me</a></li>
      <li><a class="Resume" href="">Resume</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="headerImage">
  <img src="/Images/greenvalley-pictures-IPbClYwlSEA-unsplash.jpg">
  </img>
  <h2>Cool Subtitle Here!</h2>
</div>
<section>
  <div class="AboutMeContainer">
    <div class="mainheaderscontainer">
      <h3 class="mainheaders">About<br>Me</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="aboutMeParagraphContainer">
      <p class="aboutMeParagraph">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, quia? nipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ratione ut veritatis assumenda, harum magnam illum sit earum quia nemo consectetur repudiandae, perspiciatis libero optio
        quidem quos porro nostrum enim sapiente molestias? Quo aut autem impedit expedita blanditiis aspernatur voluptatum nam. ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
        ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
        sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="Workcontainer">
    <div class="mainheaderscontainer" id="mainworkcontainer">
      <h4 class="mainheaders">Work</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
<section class="workImages">
  <article class="imagecard" id="bigimage">
    <img src="Images/B1B53B46-28D4-4E02-ADA5-018744EF7222_1_201_a.jpeg">
    <section class="Title">
      <div>Project</div>
    </section>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to the layout and the CSS. One of the things I did was give the `<img>`s `width: 100%`

```css
.AboutMeContainer {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.mainheaders {
  color: rgb(101, 118, 143);
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  padding-left: 95px;
 
}

.mainheaderscontainer {
  display: flex;
  padding-inline: 6px 20px;
  border-right: 3px solid rgb(101, 118, 143);
  
}

.aboutMeParagraphContainer {
  padding-inline: 20px;
  padding-right: 80px
}

.Workcontainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 16px;
}

#mainworkcontainer {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
} 

.workImages {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
  
.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
  
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}
  
.imagecard {
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: flex;
  padding-inline: 20px;
  padding-right: 80px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  border: solid rgb(101, 118, 143);
  flex: 1;
  height: calc(100% - 5px);
}

.imagecard:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.imagecard img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <h1>Lerantino</h1>
        <nav class="topnav">
            <ul>
           <li><a class="AboutMe" href="">About Me</a></li>
           <li><a class="Work" href=""> Work</a></li>
           <li><a class="Contact Me" href="">Contact Me</a></li>
           <li><a class="Resume" href="">Resume</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
   </header>
    <div class="headerImage">
        <img src="/Images/greenvalley-pictures-IPbClYwlSEA-unsplash.jpg">
</img>
<h2>Cool Subtitle Here!</h2>
</div>
<section>
    <div class="AboutMeContainer">
        <div class="mainheaderscontainer">
          <h3 class="mainheaders">About<br>Me</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="aboutMeParagraphContainer">
          <p class="aboutMeParagraph">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, quia? nipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ratione ut veritatis assumenda, harum magnam illum sit earum quia nemo consectetur repudiandae, perspiciatis libero optio
            quidem quos porro nostrum enim sapiente molestias? Quo aut autem impedit expedita blanditiis aspernatur voluptatum nam. ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
            ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
            sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="Workcontainer">
    <div class="mainheaderscontainer" id="mainworkcontainer">
    <h4 class="mainheaders">Work</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="big imagecard">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a7/Jonquil_flowers06.jpg/473px-Jonquil_flowers06.jpg">
          <section class="Title">
            <div>Project</div>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="imagecard">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7f/LotusBud0048a.jpg/420px-LotusBud0048a.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="imagecard">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Detailaufnahme_Weihnachtsstern_-_gro%C3%9F.jpg/474px-Detailaufnahme_Weihnachtsstern_-_gro%C3%9F.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```